# Include virtual host for all subdomains

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.2

I'm using the below to set a client env variable which my system requires.

```
SetEnvIf HOST "^(\w+).domain.com" CLIENT_ID=$1
UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /home/user/clients/%-3/
```

I'm including this in a vhost.conf on my main domain and it seems to be working, however the DOCUMENT_ROOT isn't being set on line 3 - it remains as the main domain doc root. I've tried with and without `UseCanonicalName Off`

What's missing here from this config? I can load files under the document root but the SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is always /usr/local/apache/htdocs

I also need this config to 404 correctly if the folder under 'clients' doesn't exist.

--

I should note that our systems allows all sites to run from a single index.php which is aliased in another virtual host include as:

```
Alias /index.php /home/public/index.php
```

This means content is served using the above config, and correctly, just the doc root isn't being set correctly.

--

It looks like this https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26052 is my document root problem.

Will try to update and come back with my findings.

Comment: So it's serving content from somewhere other than the `VirtualDocumentRoot`?  Do you have both that and a `DocumentRoot` defined?  Why is it configured in that way, and can you provide the full config?

Comment: @ShaneMadden I updated the question to include my explanation

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense.  Are you seeing the wrong docroot in what's passed to PHP, or in content that's served that isn't handled by index.php?

Comment: The content being served through the index.php gives the wrong doc root.